# PhpStorm pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I've got Github and the git executable configured in PhpStorm.

So I did VCS -> Import to Version Control -> Share on Github. I entered the name and it created the repository fine. However it did not do an initial commit.

Now when I go to VCS -> Commit Changes, it simply says "No changes detected". What? There is nothing committed in the repository when I log into Github.

Why is something so simple so difficult? Why did it not do an initial commit? How do I do an initial commit? And going forward, how do I do a quick commit of all changes I made quickly and easily?

I really want to keep this IDE and not go back to Notepad++ and the Git bash.

Comment: Have you checked that the files you modified where added to those git is tracking (command line `git add <filename>`)?

Comment: I restarted the IDE and it seems to have worked the 2nd time I tried.